# How can I change the colors AUCTeX set for some keywords?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am using emacs + AUCTeX to edit my documents.

AUCTeX seems to override many colors, which are annoyingly high contrast. It made keywords stand out so much more than the contents, which is not what I want. I prefer much lower contrast themes, but colors of keywords, section titles, etc. are always bright yellow, red, etc. Is there a way to stop the overriding or change the colors that AUCTeX set for these keywords?

Thank you!

Comment: You can customize all AUCTeX faces with `M-x customize-group RET font-latex-highlighting-faces RET`.  To tell the truth, I use custom setup and I don't have any bright yellow face.

Answer (score 4):

To customize the font color, you can do as giordano said in is comment `M-x customize-group RET font-latex-highlighting-faces RET`.

Another solution is to modify the emacs theme: `M-x customize-themes`. Several basic themes are defined.

If you want more choice, you can find website that show some theme and how to have them for example [emacsthemes](http://emacsthemes.com/).